# rsync transfer 'Broken pipe (32)' connection dropping

Tags: bash, ssh, debian, rsync, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to create a small script to transfer a lot of images from a proxmox VM to a raspberry pi on the same LAN (around 70 GB of images/videos).
This is not always working as intended, since I keep experiencing the rsync connection dropping at random. This is not happening on the same file or directory. This changes every time it fails.
The error I am getting is:

```
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)  
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] sent 8888398299 bytes  received 24769 bytes  total size 43016448521  
2023/06/21 03:05:28 [902423] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(823) [sender=3.2.3]
```

I feel like I have been all around the internet by now. Or else it is just because I am not searching for the right keywords.
I've tried to add `ServerAliverInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to `~/.ssh/config` on the sending host to no avail.
Others suggest that it might have to do with a lack of memory. I am not entirely sure how one would test this, but I have kept an eye on the memory usage on the sending host, as well as the receiving end, this doesn't seem to be the problem either.

Some then suggest that you use scp instead of rsync. I just don't like the idea of changing, since I would like to use some of the features of rsync down the line (such as file matching).
Also, I don't see the reason to change, since this gotta work somehow.

Here's a little about my setup:

- Sender: Proxmox VM (docker host)

  - 4 CPU cores (Proxmox host running on i5-8259U)
  - 6 GB RAM (usually 500 MB free RAM + 4 GB swap)
- Receiver: Raspberry Pi 4B

  - 4 GB RAM

VM is running a fully updated Debian, and the Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian OS - also fully updated. It should also be noted that the rsync version is the same on both hosts.

While rsync was running, I have tried to have a continuous ping going. This does not show any sign of network problems.
Does anyone have a clue to what I can try to make this work?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if script is run with root privileges
if [[ "$EUID" -ne '0' ]]; then
  echo "Missing root privileges"
  exit
fi

if [[ "$EUID" -eq '0' ]]; then
  # Rsync data dirs
  rsync -caPv --log-file='/home/user/backuplog/library-transfer.log' '/srv/docker/data-dir/' backupHost:'/mnt/hdd/docker/data/library-`date +"%d%m%Y"`/'
fi
```

Edit (reply to Ipor Sircer):
VM:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31

Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    SIMD, asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
```

RPi:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31

Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 32-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    no SIMD, no asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: `backupHost:...` should be on the same line as `rsync`. If it's correct in the script, please fix the code snippet in the question.

Comment: ```\`date +"%d%m%Y"\```` is inside single quotes, so it won't be expanded.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I missed that one when posting.  
Also, the date somehow works, but I will fix that.

Comment: @Cyrus I haven't ever heard of that site. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Barmar FYI to do code-formatting on leading/trailing backticks in comments, [use backslashes to escape them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347313/343832). 
`\`\\`date +"%d%m%Y"\\`\`` renders as `\`date +"%d%m%Y"\``

Comment: @wjandrea I did backslash it. But I guess that doesn't work inside triple backticks,  and now it's too late to edit.

Comment: try with `-vvv` to get more debug info.

Comment: Different -not fully compatible- rsync versions?

Comment: @pynexj I have now tried this, but it doesn't add anything useful. The connection still drops very suddenly.

Comment: @IporSircer since I am not very familiar with stackoverflow yet, I have made an edit to my original question, to show the output of rsync -V. The most noticeable difference I can see, is that my raspberry pi does not support SIMD and asm like my VM does. Do you think this means anything?

Comment: As for the memory possibility (because it could be a transient burst that puts you over the limit -- monitoring with tools that just periodically poll won't necessarily help), read the `dmesg` logs; if the OOM killer is active it'll show up there.

Comment: In general if you want a _certain_ answer one gets into tracing tools -- sysdig, strace, ebftrace, etc -- but being on a resource-constrained system limits your options a bit there (strace has a huge performance penalty, and all of them generate very large logs you need to be able to store somewhere).

Comment: (BTW, in general I'd call this more a [unix.se] question than a Stack Overflow one; the focus is on troubleshooting behavior of UNIX tools more than writing code).

Comment: Also, while you've tried telling rsync to be verbose, you might think about telling the copy of ssh that rsync is using as a transport to be verbose; that'll give you more clarity about whether it's the child process or the transport itself that dies first. (But if you get a proper trace, that'll answer these questions for you).